# h,b and sup tags do nothing + more problems

Tags: html, css

For the past hour I've been trying to figure out:

1. why can't I edit text inside HTML;
2. why h or b or sup tags won't work for me;
3. If I set a font-size for the h2 (to make them work how they were supposed to), then that font-size won't change when re-scaling the size of the window.
   Why is the font size of h tags static if I made a rule in css that should re-scale all of the body's font-size according to that formula (which is not mine) ?!

I am a complete noob ! What I wrote there is what I took from https://www.w3schools.com/ and https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/ .

```css
#Buton1 {
    
    
        background-color: darkorange;
        color:white;
        text-aling: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 
    
    
}


#whole {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    
    
}


 body {
  font-size: calc(14px + (26 - 14) * ((100vw - 300px) / (1600 - 300)));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="reset.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="Style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>PlantAnApp</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="whole">
            
        <div class="Module_1">
            <h2>Think an app.</h2>
            <h2><b>Plant an app</b></h2>
            <h2>Grow an app.</h2>
            <p><b>Are you up to the challenge of building your<br> own web-app</b> with mentor guidance between <br>July 1<sup>st</sup> and July 31<sup>st</sup></p>
            <button type="button" a href="" id="Buton1">READ ON</button>
            
        
        
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="Module_2">
            <h2>What is</h2>
            <h2>Plant an App?</h2>
            <div>Plant an App is a platform that <br>empowers you to build and customize<br> epic web apps, fast and with low/no<br> code requirements.</div>
            <br>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <h2><b>What can you build ? </b></h2>
        </div>
         
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I fixed the bold problem by adding this line of code inside the reset stylesheet: b {font-weight:bold;}

Answer (score 0):

> why can't I edit text inside HTML

If you mean in the browser, text input is only allowed via `<input>`, `<textarea>` or `contenteditable` DOM nodes.  (And if you want that text input to persist across page loads, you need to store it somewhere, either in a server database or in the user's localstorage, and retrieve it again on page load; if this is what you're aiming for you'll probably want to follow a specific tutorial, it's more than can really be answered in a single Q&A.)

> why h or b or sup tags won't work for me;

They do work in your snippet here. I'm guessing the reason they're not working in your project is because your CSS reset is resetting all the default styles for those tags.  Use a less overzealous reset, or remember to restyle the tags you want to use after resetting.

> Why is the font size of h tags static if I made a rule in css that should re-scale all of the body's font-size

I'm not sure what's going on with that rule, but it doesn't seem to return a valid size, possibly because of the mixing of unit and unitless values; safari at least is simply ignoring that rule.   Simplify that calculation, and check to make sure it isn't also being overridden by your style reset.  (If you can clarify what font sizes you were trying to get in relation to the browser window, we may be able to help you fix it.)

Comment: Thank you ! It helped a lot !
The problem I've got now is that I made the whole text to resize but I can't give each div or p of text an initial value that will continue to resize.
Now all my text is the same size and it can resize with the window.

Comment: If you need to size individual elements, put rules on those elements instead of on the body.